# For every value in column loop through table and copy row of every instance, paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

For each value in Sheet("Scrap2") Column A.

find all matching instances of this value in column A of Sheet("VA_Data"). copy entire row and paste to first empty Row on sheet("List")

My code right now basically only copys the first instance it comes to of the match and then moves to the next value in Sheet("Scrap2").

If there are 10 cells in col A of sheet "VA_Data" that match the first value of Scrap2, then those 10 rows need to copy entire row and paste to first empty rows on sheet "List".

any help is appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Loop_VA_Data()
    
Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim wsb As Worksheet
Dim wsc As Worksheet
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim stra As String
Dim rng As Range

On Error GoTo errLoop_VA_Data

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsa = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scrap2")
    Set wsb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VA_Data")
    Set wsc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
    
    wsa.Range("B:B").Clear
    wsc.Rows("2:" & wsc.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1).Clear
    a = 2
    
    Do
    
        If Trim(wsa.Cells(a, 1).Value) = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        stra = Trim(wsa.Cells(a, 1).Value)
        
        Set rng = wsb.Range("A:A").Find(What:=stra, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not (rng Is Nothing) Then
            b = rng.Row
            c = wsc.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
            wsb.Rows(b).Copy wsc.Rows(c)
            wsa.Cells(a, 2).Value = "Found on row " & b
        Else
            wsa.Cells(a, 2).Value = "Not Found"
        End If
        
        If Not (rng Is Nothing) Then
            Set rng = Nothing
        End If
        
        a = a + 1
    
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Complete!", vbInformation
    
    GoTo closeout
    
    Exit Sub
    
errLoop_VA_Data:
    MsgBox "Err Number is: " & Err.Number & " / Err Desc is: " & Err.Description & " in sub Loop_VA_Data!", vbCritical
    
closeout:
    If Not (wsa Is Nothing) Then
        Set wsa = Nothing
    End If
    
    If Not (wsb Is Nothing) Then
        Set wsb = Nothing
    End If
    
    If Not (wsc Is Nothing) Then
        Set wsc = Nothing
    End If
    
    If Not (rng Is Nothing) Then
        Set rng = Nothing
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Filter would be better here i.e. `Filter` for your target value and then work with the resultant visible range (`xlCellTypeVisible`)

Comment: You need to use `FindNext` to find further instances. You should also get rid of the Gotos and On Errors which conceal problems.

Comment: Can you show me how to incorporate FindNext into my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @urdearboy has the right idea - using a filter & copying en masse.  The following code assumes the data on your `VA_Data` sheet is contiguous.  Let me know how you go with it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Filter_Copy()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim c As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, PasteRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Scrap2")
Set ws2 = Sheets("VA_Data")
Set ws3 = Sheets("List")
LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(LastRow, 1))
    With ws2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter 1, c.Value
        PasteRow = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy ws3.Range("A" & PasteRow)
        .AutoFilter
    End With
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: This got me what I was looking for. I did not need to show all the data that was on "VA_Data" on the "List" sheet, so I added a Row Delete based on the total number of rows coming from "VA_Data". This left me with just the new matched rows I needed.

Comment: Good to hear:) Please mark the answer as accepted if it works so others may find it. Thank you.